# How does eldoc (>= 1.1.0) display arguments in the mode-line during eval-expression

Tags: mode-line, minibuffer, eldoc

I am unable to determine how eldoc is displaying arguments (or other information) in the mode-line while `eval-expression` is reading user input in the minibuffer. I could not find a relevant element in the default value of `mode-line-format` and I also did not find any code where eldoc is prepending an element temporarily to the (local?) value of `mode-line-format`.

I need this so that I can change the visual appearance, such as its background color.

Note that I did find the complex machinery that determines *what* information to display; that's not what I am looking for, I only wonder *how* that information is displayed, whatever it may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it:

```
(defun eldoc-minibuffer-message (format-string &rest args)
  "Display messages in the mode-line when in the minibuffer.
Otherwise work like `message'."
```

?

It seems that it prepends `eldoc-mode-line-string` to `mode-line-format` and clears it on a `minibuffer-exit-hook`:

```
    (add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook
          (lambda () (setq eldoc-mode-line-string nil
                  ;; https://debbugs.gnu.org/16920
                  eldoc-last-message nil))
          nil t)
...
        (setq mode-line-format
          (list "" '(eldoc-mode-line-string
                 (" " eldoc-mode-line-string " "))
            mode-line-format)))
```

It also does a `(force-mode-line-update)`. Not a very polite way to do it, it could just have written to the `global-mode-string` or added its own lighter...

See how it looks with doom-modeline :(

[image]

The heading bar is displaced to the right. Fortunately moody-modeline won't be affected like this, although I don't know how well it plays with ribbons and tabs.

NOTE: all of the above is from emacs-28 branch.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious now that I look at it again... oO I think I should go to bed.

Comment: "I don't know how well it plays with ribbons and tabs" yeah, I fear that's gonna require some redefining.